# How to display a form of multiple rows from the database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to build a form that displays a list of patients with data from multiple tables. But I'm unable to figure out how to display multiple records from different tables.

I've got the basics of this set up I think. I'm just not sure how to fill in the blanks in the controller to get this to work together. My query in the WorklistRepository doesn't seem to return the data I'm expecting.

ExtractionFormType.php

```
class ExtractionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('first_name',  TextType::class, ['disabled' => 'true'])
            ->add('accession_number', TextType::class, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('extraction_number', TextType::class, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('elution_volume', IntegerType::class, ['attr' => array('style' => 'background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153)'), 'data'=> 30])
            ->add('sample_volume', IntegerType::class, ['attr' => array('style' => 'background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153)'), 'data'=> 1])
            ->add('qubit_reading', IntegerType::class, ['disabled'=> true])
            ->add('dilution_volume', NumberType::class, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('hydration_volume', NumberType::class, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('final_concentration', NumberType::class, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('final_volume', NumberType::class, ['disabled' => true]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ExtractionFormModel::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

ExtractionFormModel.php

```
class ExtractionFormModel
{

    public $first_name;

    public $accession_number;

    public $extraction_number;

    public $elution_volume;

    public $sample_volume;

    public $qubit_reading;

    public $dilution_volume;

    public $hydration_volume;

    public $final_concentration;

    public $final_volume;
}
```

I have 5 tables I need to get data from to populate the form.
worklist 
sample_extraction
patient_sample
patient_order
patient

In the WorklistRepository I created a function to query these tables but debugging it doesn't show that it returns anything but the data about the worklist itself.

WorklistRepository.php

```
    public function getWorklistDetails(int $id): ?array {
        return  $this->createQueryBuilder('wd')
            ->leftJoin('wd.sampleExtractions', 'se')
            ->leftJoin('se.PatientSample', 'ps')
            ->leftJoin('ps.patientOrders', 'po')
            ->leftJoin('ps.patient', 'p')
            ->where('wd.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
```

WorklistController.php

I'm just using the show route in the Worklist controller for now. I can get the form to show but obviously no data.

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="worklist_show", methods={"GET"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Worklist $worklist
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, Worklist $worklist): Response
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(ExtractionFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            return $this->redirectToRoute('worklist_index');
        }

        return $this->render('worklist/show.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
```

Comment: Start by figuring out why your query does not seem to work.  The way it is written it should return an array of one Worklist entity with your Extraction entities stored in Worklist::sampleExtractions.  Once you understand that then you will probably need a WorklistFormType which [embeds a collection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) of ExtractionFormTypes.

Comment: I wrote the query in regular SQL and got the data I was expecting. I realized that this was returning a Worklist entity during debugging and thought maybe I just didn't know how to access the rest of the data from the query as I could see the name of the worklist but not any of the details from the join.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code snippet:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id): Response
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $worklist= $em->getRepository('App:Worklist')->getWorklistDetails($id);

    if(null === $worklist) {
        return $this->createNotFoundException('Worklist with id ' . $id . ' not found!');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(ExtractionFormType::class, $worklist);
    //...
```

Comment: I'd done something similar to this - with your code it says there is no getWorklistDetails.                                                                                                           ```                                                                                                                          $worklist = $worklistRepository->getWorklistDetails($worklist->id);                                               ```                                                                                                                                              I get an error.

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Form::createView() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView or null, string given,

Comment: if the error is that there is no function getWorklistDetails then you know that something must be wrong with your repository. Has the entity file Workflow the right annotations?

Comment: Which version do you use of Symfony?

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was passing the Repository in as an argument to the show() function and trying to access it that way. I wasn't aware that it needed annotations and could be accessed they way you showed me. I am using Symfony 4.3.

Comment: If I use $worklist = $em->getRepository(Worklist::class)->getWorklistDetails($id); it shows the function as available. Trying to display I the error: "The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class App\Form\Model\OncoExQuantDilFormModel, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of App\Form\Model\OncoExQuantDilFormModel."

Comment: I managed to get rid of that error by removing the public function configureOptions in the FormType class. I'm still not getting the data for some reason though.

Comment: How looks your controller now? You can update your question. Is there data in the $worklist entity? Can you debug that?